# Estimating Weibull density parameters (error: "...initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite")

Tags: r, statistics, weibull

I am trying to estimate the shape and scale of a data set.
I used two different ways and for both I got an error message:

First, I tried by moments using the `survey` package:

```
survreg(Surv(all.ws)~1, dist="weibull")
```

I got the error message:

> invalid survival times for this distribution

Second, I tried using `fitdistr()` function:

```
fitdistr(all.ws, densfun=dweibull, start=list(scale=1, shape=2))
```

I got an error message:

> Error in optim(x=c(2.2, 2.1,1.9....:
>   initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite

What is wrong with what I am doing?

Comment: try maybe on http://www.crossvalidated.com .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A google search "fitdistr Weibull Error" shows this exact question was discussed a year ago on the R-help mailing list: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Problems-with-fitdistr-td1334772.html

Some points from that link:

- zeros in your data will cause problems
- use pelwei() function from package lmom

Comment: apparently because it takes a log, not sure though.

Comment: @Prasad Any chance you could update the answer showing _how_ to use pelwei function to solve this as I'm having the same difficulty myself. It's returning 3x parameters whereas I'm looking for just 2x (shape and scale for Weibull). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when using fitdistr() with a Beta distribution. In that case both **ones** and zeros in the data produced this error.

Additionally I found that when the limit argument is used in the fitdistr() call, a different error is produced:
eg (where x is a vector of samples containing a 1.0 or 0):

`fitdistr(x, "beta", list(shape1 = 1, shape2 = 0.2),lower=0.001)`

```
   `Error in stats::optim: L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'`
```